# Conditional HTML

Tags: angularjs

I have this very simple `ng-repeat` that creates accordions. I removed the `in` class from it so they are closed. But what I actually want it to open the first and close all the others.

Any idea how can I do this?

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion{{ticket.TICKET_ID}}">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion{{ticket.TICKET_ID}}" href="#collapse{{ticket.TICKET_ID}}">{{ticket.TICKET_ID}} - {{ticket.TITLE}} ({{ticket.TICKET_STATUS_DESCRIPTION}})</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse{{ticket.TICKET_ID}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">
          {{ticket.DESCRIPTION}}
          <hr>
          <span><b>Contacted by: </b> {{ticket.TICKET_TYPE_DESCRIPTION}}</span><br>
          <span><b>Category: </b> {{ticket.TICKET_CATEGORY_DESCRIPTION}}</span><br>
          <span><b>Related to: </b> {{ticket.TICKET_TAG_DESCRIPTION}}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-footer">{{ticket.CREATED_BY}} - {{ticket.CREATION_DATE}}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: since the class `in` wasn't used, it's not very clear where it's added, however, you can try to check for an index before adding a class with: `ng-class="{'in': $index == 0}"`

Comment: it is added here: `<div id="collapse{{ticket.TICKET_ID}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">` this is bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-class` to selectively add the `collapse` class, which stops the first panel collapsing :

```
 <div id="collapse{{ticket.TICKET_ID}}" class="panel-collapse" ng-class="{ 'collapse': $index !== 0 }">
   <div class="panel-body">
     ...
```

I've knocked up an example here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NzMexQ?editors=1010